# Raising PermissionDenied in context processor

Tags: python, django

I have a context items that are required by almost every page in my site, but that require privileged access. To retrieve these, I've created a custom context processor. If the user in the request is authenticated and is does not have access to the context necessary for the pages they are viewing, I want the site to return a 403, so I tried raising `PermissionDenied` in the context processor.

As you might have guessed, this doesn't work well. Basically, the site now just raises the exception instead of catching it and returning a 403. This is not my desired behavior.

Is there a (not-too-hacked) way to get a context processor to cause a Django site to return a 403 Permission Denied response?

Comment: Context processors can only update the current context, not modify the response. You may want to write a middleware instead.

Comment: https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2015/07/understanding-django-middlewares/